# cocos2d-x3.2 no std::string, std::vector...etc in Eclipse

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I've created a cocos2d-x3.2 project and imported into Eclipse with 'Existing Android Code Into Workspace' and everything is working except there's no std library. Basically, everything runs except I can't use std::string, std::vector...etc.

I normally use xcode or visual studio, I don't know the settings in Eclipse. I've tried messing with settings I've found from google and it just made it worse.

Apparently, when I import as C++ project std::string etc show up but now I can't launch Android project.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Couldn't get it to work and since no answer, I've discovered cocos2d-x3.2 has its own vector and string.
cocos2d::Vector<T> and __String to create C string. e.g. __String::create( "a string" );

Comment: But the cocos2d::Vector<T> can hold only CCObject types only. I too looking for an answer what will happen if I use std::vector in xcode and then build for android later.

Answer (score -1):

you can use std::string in your code. But you have to import these libraries

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
```